# How do I find the index of a sheet?

Tags: python, list

I just started to learn programming, and I chose the first language Python. And I have a question about lists. If my list is in another list, how can I find out its index?
example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf4kR.png)

Comment: Please show an example. I don’t understand what you mean.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a ``list.index`` method?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no

Comment: Well, you might want to read [the documentation on lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), then.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, the list is a heterogeneous type, it can have numbers and strings and list dict or set inside a list.

a = [1,2,3,4,[5,6,7]]
a[1]
Output : 2

a[2]
Output: 3

a[4][1]

output: 6
At index 4 list contain sublist and in sublist, it will look for index 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of list:

`List = [[10,13,17],[3,5,1],[13,11,12]]`

If you want to access a certain index:

`>>> List[0][1] --> 13`

If this is not what you were after then you have to specify the question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you have a list inside of a list such as this

```
my_array = [[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]]
```

You interact with it as though it's a list of lists, meaning

```
my_array[0] = [1, 2, 3]
my_array[1] = [4, 5, 6]
my_array[2] = [7, 8, 9]
```

And if you want the index of 6 it would be my_array[1][2] because it's the third item in the second list
Hopefully this helps. And for your future googling we call these 2d-arrays you can learn more here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_2darray.htm